# Get sides of triangle when we have one side, one angle and relationship between the remaining sides

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to find the length of a in this triangle where b has a known relationship to a. Known values are the length of c, the angle α and the constant k. How do I get the value of a in this scenario?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the cosine theorem we have
$$a^2=c^2+k^2a^2-2kac\cos\alpha$$
Which becomes an equation in $a$
$$a^2 \left(1-k^2\right)+2 a \,c \,k \cos \alpha -c^2=0$$
if $k=1$ there is one solution 
$$a=\frac{c}{2\cos\alpha}$$
if $k\ne 1\land 0\le k\le \frac{1}{\sin\alpha}$ there are two solutions
$$a=\frac{c \left(k \cos \alpha \pm\sqrt{1-k^2 \sin \alpha }\right)}{k^2-1}$$
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use *cosine* rule, to form a quadratic in $a$. Depending on specific value, there may be one or two values of $a$.

$$\cos(\alpha) = \frac{k^2a^2 + c^2 - a^2}{2kac}$$

Answer (score 0):

One has $$\cos \alpha = \frac{k^2a^2+c^2-a^2}{2kac}$$. So, one has $b=ka = \sqrt{a^2-c^2+2kac\cos \alpha}$